# Tailwind Flex: Overflow when a long line of text is shown

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

This is a very strange behavior I'm getting from Flex classes in tailwind. I guess you can somehow translate it to CSS but I want to stay in a tailwind solution. Let me explain:

If you run the following code snippet, you will see that in the first case, the line overflows, even if I try with the `break-words` class. That doesn't happen with `break-all` class, but I don't wan't to use that class as it could breaks words.

When you output some normal text, it behaves as you expect.

Is this an issue? Am I being perfectionist?

Thanks!

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- My problem. It should break the line and avoid the overflow-->
<div class="flex bg-gray-200">
  <div class="flex-initial text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2">
    Short
  </div>
  <div class="flex-initial text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2 break-words">
    asuperultraloooooooooonglineoftexoverhereitfeelslikeitdoesnotendddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
  </div>
</div>

<!-- When words are smaller it behaves just fine! -->
<div class="flex bg-gray-200">
  <div class="flex-initial text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2">
    Short
  </div>
  <div class="flex-initial text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2 break-words">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui ad labore ipsam, aut rem quo repellat esse tempore id, quidem
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well I have OCD too. Things like these make me go crazy.

Comment: @ManojKumar haha it's not about OCD. It feels like a toy, and some users might think that they have broken the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple ways to fix this

**Add also overflow: hidden**

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- My problem. It should break the line and avoid the overflow-->
<div class="flex bg-gray-200">
  <div class="flex-initial text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2">
    Short
  </div>
  <div class="flex-initial text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2 break-words overflow-hidden">
    asuperultraloooooooooonglineoftexoverhereitfeelslikeitdoesnotendddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
  </div>
</div>

<!-- When words are smaller it behaves just fine! -->
<div class="flex bg-gray-200">
  <div class="flex-initial text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2">
    Short
  </div>
  <div class="flex-initial text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2 break-words">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui ad labore ipsam, aut rem quo repellat esse tempore id, quidem
  </div>
</div>
```

**Set static width**

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- My problem. It should break the line and avoid the overflow-->
<div class="flex bg-gray-200">
  <div class="flex-initial text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2">
    Short
  </div>
  <div class="w-64 flex-initial text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2 break-words">
    asuperultraloooooooooonglineoftexoverhereitfeelslikeitdoesnotendddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
  </div>
</div>

<!-- When words are smaller it behaves just fine! -->
<div class="flex bg-gray-200">
  <div class="flex-initial text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2">
    Short
  </div>
  <div class="flex-initial text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2 break-words">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui ad labore ipsam, aut rem quo repellat esse tempore id, quidem
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to find another ways as well but to be honest I'm not 100% sure why this is happening - I'm not flexbox expert.